# Identifying PCB components with metal tops, no other markings visible

Tags: pcb, identification, components

I am trying to troubleshoot a broken PCB and I am struggling to identify these 6 components with metal case.

What are they, and is it possible to test them without removing?

[image: part of PCB showing 6 devices with metal tops]

Comment: What kind of board is it?

Comment: Why not tell us what the function of the PCB is? Did you find it in an ion-thruster control panel for an inter-stellar rocket or in a laptop? Was there a heatsink attached (with the thermal paste causing the white on the board)? Hit the [edit] link.

Comment: What is the broken device? It would at least give some context to make it easier to recognize.

Comment: Regardless, you can't really test most components on board.

Comment: @xx102 - Hi, FYI these are the current "[Component Identification Question Guidelines](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6710)". The more information you can supply from that list, the better the chances of identification. As already commented, supplying a description of the device (and in this case, adding a photo of the whole PCB, to give context to the part with those 6 devices) might help to narrow down the type of device. However, without any part numbers visible, this question might not be answerable. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like dummy pieces of metal given no pins and surrounding components not mounted, or have OP desoldered them?

Comment: There's no particular reason to suspect that these have anything to do with the unstated failure.  If you want to repair this, you need to understand how it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 4):

My best guess is these are heat spreaders with no actual electrical connections, intended to couple heat into a rear mounted heatsink for forward side components

The bottom left one is the main tip off

So I suspect these may be nickel plated copper blocks

If they do have electrical connections, try cleaning with isoproyl alcohol and a toothbrush, if you can see a white ceramic with gold connections on the side you may be in military grade electronics land.

Answer (score 1):

Those are military-grade ceramic flatpacks with metal lids.

Comment: Unlikely especially not with the grossly visible "alignment error" that would create a pad-to-pad short if it were the actual ic.  They're heat spreaders merely stuck on with thermal paste.